# Change USB VID and PID (Leonardo)

Tags: usb, arduino-leonardo

I'm new to using electronic boards, and have followed a guide online for printing a 6 DoF (degree of freedom) mouse. I'm stuck on an optional step that requires me to change the PID and VID of a "Arduino Leonardo" board.

I've located the appropriate "boards.txt" file, but I'm not sure which line to change. I've edited a few, but I'm worried I'll mess things up ([a tutorial for it](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/customize-your-arduino/6983) mentions they had destroyed 3 trying to rename it, and is back from 2009), and the ones I've changed do not result in a change.

I have checked out previous questions people have made regarding this topic, but quite frankly I can't understand the technical terms used in those.

[This is the code in question](https://pastebin.com/z7yZXiBB) I'm trying to compile, and lists example PID and VIDs as well.

I would love a clear explanation on which PID/VID I need to edit in the "boards.txt", so I can safely modify the board to be read as the space mouse in the code.

Comment: The Vendor ID (i.e. Logitech, Zerbra, ect) and Product ID (i.e. Specific Mouse made by Logitech, specific bar code reader by Zebra, ect) are values paid for by companies who manufacture USB peripherals.  When you use one of these VID/PID combinations you are telling your computer "your device is their device".  It's probably not on the up-n-up and you likely can't openly sell your USB product w/ "their VID/PID values". That said, you can probably make almost any VID/PID work on a Linux computer. On a Windows computer you probably have to masquerade as the USB peripheral you are imitating.

Comment: I see, that's understandable, selling products like that would fit pretty well under scamming and deceiving people. This is for a 3D printed project for my own personal use. Is it possible to change the right PID though, or is it sort of a territory where people aren't willing to openly discuss it since there's no real way to prove I'm not using it to mislead others?

Comment: I don't see a problem doing this for personal use.  Your question sounded like you didn't know what VID and PID numbers were used for.  So, a little background.  I'd write an answer ... but I'm still not clear if just knowing what a VID/PID number answered your question.

As for bricking your Arduino, well, if there is only 1 USB on your Arduino and you change the VID/PID away from being a USB/CDC device, then the connected computer will likely not talk to it.  But this has more to do w/with the processor (or USB interface device) used in your particular Arduino.

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". This is not a forum. Then come back and [edit] your question for clarification. -- I will not look into externally linked sources on _some_ website. Can't you show a minimal example? -- The tutorial is not for the Leonardo, AFAIK the Leonardo does not use an FTDI chip for USB. -- What is this "boards.txt" you mention? -- _Why_ do you need to change the VID/PID at all? -- Please provide a link to this "_guide online_".

Comment: *I'm stuck on an optional step that requires me to change the PID and VID of a "Arduino Leonardo" board.* - If it's optional and you are stuck, I suggest ignoring that step. If it's optional it can hardly **require** you to do it.

Comment: @thebusybee *What is this "boards.txt" you mention?* - Really? [boards.txt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/boards.txt) is a well-known file that specifies baud rates, processor types, fuse settings and so on, generally used during the process of uploading code to a board. I'm not sure of the exact way it is used, but my guess is that the IDE reads that file in, populates its list of supported boards, and then when you choose one, sets up various defines used in the compile and uploading process.

Comment: *I need to edit in the "boards.txt", so I can safely modify the board to be read as the space mouse in the code.* - What's a "space mouse"?

Comment: @NickGammon `This code makes your Arduino act as a 3DConnexion SpaceMouse`. The "space mouse" is the "6 DoF (degree of freedom) mouse" they mentioned.

Comment: @NickGammon *"The tutorial is not for the Leonardo, AFAIK the Leonardo does not use an FTDI chip for USB. "* Pretty sure the idea is that the FTDI chip *seems to contraindicate* a normal Leonardo and by extension the normal boards.txt. That is, the busybee is NOT asking "what is this boards.txt thing you speak of?".  They're asking the OP to positively identify the *specific* boards.txt, which may or may not wind up being the on you've linked to. And that will potentially answer half a dozen questions. That's what I get out of it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Leave "boards.txt" alone. It is wrong side of your goal.]

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr

```
leonardo.build.mcu=atmega32u4
leonardo.build.f_cpu=16000000L
leonardo.build.vid=0x2341     <--- here
leonardo.build.pid=0x8036
leonardo.build.usb_product="Arduino Leonardo"
```

---

```
leonardo.build.vid=0x256f
leonardo.build.pid=0xc631
leonardo.build.usb_product="SpaceMouse Pro Wireless (cabled)"
```